# Change text from search box when no product found

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am developing a WordPress site with WooCommerce and the search box displays the text "No products found." text when a product is not available.

How do I change this text to something else "don't worry try again later"

[image]

I am not sure how to approach this as I am pretty new to this kind of modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product' );

function woocommerce_register_post_type_product( $labels ) {
    $labels[ 'labels' ][ 'not_found' ] = __( 'don\'t worry, try again later', 'woocommerce' );
    return $labels;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `gettext` hook to change the text.

Place this in your functions.php  With the switch, you will only effect text in the "woocommerce" text domain.

```php
function dd_change_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'No products found' :
            if ($domain == 'woocommerce'){
                $translated_text = __( "Don\'t worry try again later", 'woocommerce' );
            } else {
                $translated_text = __( 'No products found', $domain );
            }
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'dd_change_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: I even changed the "No products found" for $domain but it still doesn't work. I cleared the cache also.

Comment: This worked however  $translated = str_replace( 'No products found', 'New Message', $translated );